# how to retrieve youtube search results and their video id using java?

Tags: java, youtube

i know how to retrieve all statistics if video id is given.
but if i have to retrieve video ids of search results (20) based on a query title, then i'm not able to do it.
could any one please help me how to deal with it using **JAVA API**.

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Have you searched through the Google Documentation?
Their guide has exactly what you are looking for: [YouTube API - Searching for Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos)

It even gives you an example:

```
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));
// order results by the number of views (most viewed first)
query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.VIEW_COUNT);

// search for puppies and include restricted content in the search results
query.setFullTextQuery("puppy");
query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);

VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
```

From the returned VideoFeed, you can easily get the video id.

```
for(VideoEntry videoEntry : videoFeed.getEntries() ) {
     YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = videoEntry.getMediaGroup();
     mediaGroup.getVideoId(); // the video ID
}
```

Comment: @TS..thank you so much..it's working.

Comment: YouTube recently dropped its support for RSS/Atom feeds. Following is a working workaround using YOUTUBE DATA API V3: http://www.joe0.com/2016/03/05/youtube-data-api-v3-how-to-search-youtube-using-java-and-extract-video-id-of-the-most-relevant-result/